# POST multiple lines via POSTMAN

Tags: php, json, postman

I don't know how to post multiple lines with postman. I can post single line:

```
{

    "name": {
       "en-gb": "Test 11111"
    }           

}
```

but multiple lines: not working:

```
{

    "name": [{
        "en-gb": "Test 11111"
     },
     {
        "en-gb": "Test2222"
     }]
  }
```

Comment: Please try this,[ { "name": {"en-gb": "Test 11111"}}, {"name": {"en-gb": "Test 2222"}}]

Comment: Show a snapshot of your postman request.

Comment: [not working](http://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/) is not a useful description of the problem. How are you determining it is not working? Is Postman throwing an error? Is the end point you are making the HTTP request to throwing an error? Have you added logging to the end point to find out exactly what it is recieving?

Comment: @Casper I receive "Invalid data"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your format is correct, use the `raw JSON(application/json)` option.

```
{ 
  "name": [
     { "en-gb": "Test 11111"},
     { "en-gb": "Test 22222"}
  ]
}
```

Tested and worked for me.

[image]

Response = $_POST["name"]

Answer (score 1):

Use the `raw` option to POST the whole JSON as is.

[image]

You can also add `Content-type:application/json` in the `Headers` tab.

Comment: I tried: { "name": [{"en-gb": "Test 11111"},{"en-gb": "Test 2222"}]} and receive output "{
    "name": [
        "Must be a mapping object."
    ]
}"

Comment: @Klapsius In that case, I would like to have more info on what type of data is being sent and how it is sent in postman.

Comment: I have header part with authentication (working correctly) also Content-type:application/json is set. And in body part raw flag is ticked and I can insert one single record but I don't know how to create an array for multiple lines

Comment: @Klapsius what is the API you are using? I can't say much from that error message without looking at the backend service API and it's requirements.